# How to include two SSL certificates in C# request

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect to Java web service with C# client. I don't have physical access to that service, but I was told by it's developers that I need to provide client certificate AND intermediate CA in my requests.

I tried using Service Reference and WebClient but I only managed to send just client certificate.

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);

        request.ClientCertificates.Add(m_TransportCertificate); 
        //m_TransportCertificate holds client certificate with key and rest of the cert chain (intermediate and root)

        return request;
    }
```

**How to send two client certificates in C#?** As far as i know it isn't normal behaviour - client should only send one certificate.

I can't make my app to do it - it always sends one certificate.
[Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUYgT.png)

However it works in SoapUI (the second one is intermediate CA)
[Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OcPd.png)

Comment: Could they mean that you need to install the intermediateCA on the machine that is using the client certificate?

Comment: The client should automatically send the intermediates if it trusts the chain.  This may require installing the root CA as a trusted CA on the client system, or manually installing an intermediate CA into the intermediates store.

Comment: @bartonjs That's not the case. I've installed certificates in user store. Validation of server certificate succeeded. If I uninstall these certificates then no client certificate is sent via request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Intermediate CA was automatically installed in *Intermediate Certification Authorities* but it needs to be in *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*.

Just moved it there and it worked.